# How to create part of my navigation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Now I have this pagination code:

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <ul class="unstyled inbox-pagination">
        {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
        <li>
            <a class="pl-15 pr-15"><i class="fa fa-angle-left  pagination-left"></i></a>
        </li>
        @else
        <li>
            <a class="pl-15 pr-15" href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-left  pagination-left"></i></a>
        </li>
        @endif

        {{-- Next Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <li>
            <a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right pagination-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        @else
            <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-angle-right pagination-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        @endif
    </ul>
@endif
```

And my code nov take this result:

[image]

Pagination without numbers and "Next" - "Prev" buttons. Here how I can add count of messages and get simple result:

[image]

How I can add counts and get general result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get total

```
$paginator->total()
```

To get the first item

```
$paginator->firstItem()
```

To get the last item

```
$paginator->lastItem()
```

Comment: This will work: `<li><span>{{$paginator->firstItem()}}-{{$paginator->lastItem()}} of {{$paginator->total()}}</span></li>` ?

Comment: Not sure you have to put this as an item in your <ul>.
I would rather put it as a separate element e.g. <span>{{$paginator->firstItem()}}-{{$paginator->lastItem‌​()}} of {{$paginator->total()}</span>

I mean outside of <ul> listing.